# I need help in this regural expression exercises

Tags: regular-expressions

> Write a regular expression for the language of words over $\{0,1,2\}$ satisfying the following requirements:
>
> - The word has length at least 3.
> - The last symbol is 2.
> - The second to last symbol isn't 0.
> - The combination of the last two symbols doesn’t appear anywhere else in the string.

Comment: It's really better if you solved this on your own.

Comment: Yeah I know..I  have been trying the last 3 hours but I am really stuck.I could use some guidance at least

Comment: Perhaps you could show us what you did manage to do.

Comment: (0+1+2)[(10*+11*+2*)]*(12*) I wrote this for the case where the second to last symbol is 1 but it doesn’t seem right at all

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this exercise, we need to come up for regular expressions for two classes of words:

- Words of the form $x00$, where $x \neq \epsilon$ and the only occurrence of $00$ is at the end.
- Words of the form $x01$, where $x \neq \epsilon$ and the only occurrence of $01$ is at the end.

Let us start with the first class. For starters, $x$ must end with $1$ or $2$. So such words are of one of the forms $y100$ or $y200$, where $y$ doesn't contain $00$. Presumably you already know how to describe all words not containing $00$ using a regular expression.

For the second class, the only constraints on $x$ are that it is non-empty and doesn't contain $01$. If you don't like the "non-empty" constraint, you can use the following case distinction:

- If $x = y0$ or $x = y2$, then the only constraint on $y$ is that it doesn't contain $01$.
- If $x = y1$, then $y$ cannot end with $0$. It could be empty. If it ends with $2$, then $x$ is of the form $z21$. If it ends with $1$, then we're again in the same situation: the preceding symbol (if any) cannot be $0$. Continuing in this way, we see that either $x \in 1^+$ or $x$ is of the form $y2z$, where $y$ doesn't contain $01$ and $z = 1^n$ for some $n \geq 1$.

I'll let you figure out how to describe strings $y$ avoiding $01$ – this is very similar to the case of avoiding $00$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.One more question..do you think by drawning the DFA would help me to answer the problem because I tried it and I got even more confused

Comment: I'm not sure it would be too helpful, since regular expressions are quite different from DFAs. However, there is an algorithm that converts a DFA to an equivalent regular expression.

Comment: Alright I’ll keep that in mind.